# add_query_arg() XSS Vulnerability

Tags: query

I've created a personal plugin and now I'm worried about this vulnerability: https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/04/security-advisory-xss-vulnerability-affecting-multiple-wordpress-plugins.html

This is how I use add_query_arg(). Is this fine or should I protect it in some way?

general_plugin.php

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "custom_var";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

plugin_part1.php

```
...
echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/page/?custom_var='.$db_table->db_column.'">text</a>....'
...
```

plugin_part1-fixed.php

```
...
echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/page/'.add_query_arg( "custom_var", $db_table->db_column).'">text</a>....'
...
```

plugin_part2.php

```
$id = intval(get_query_var( 'custom_var' ));
$sql = $mydb->prepare(
        "
        SELECT * 
        FROM `db_table` 
        WHERE `db_table`.`db_column` = %d
        ", 
        array($is)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something that is staring me in the face, you aren't using `add_query_arg()` or `remove_query_arg()`; since those are the only functions affected by this particular exploit you should be safe.

Your code does use the `query_vars` filter and `get_query_var()` but neither of those are effected by the exploit you've referenced.

Otherwise your code looks good, I do see a typo in the second to last line of "plugin_part2.php", it should probably be `array($id)`.  Without seeing the rest in context I can't say that you are safe with 100% certainty, but nothing you've posted is vulnerable to the exploit you're asking about.

For anyone who stumbles on this post, the fix for this particular exploit goes like this, any instance of:

```
add_query_arg($param1, $param2, $old_query_or_uri);
```

or

```
remove_query_arg($key, $query);
```

should be replaced with

```
esc_url(add_query_arg($param1, $param2, $old_query_or_uri));
```

or

```
esc_url(remove_query_arg($key, $query));
```

respectively.

An excellent write up of this exploit is available in [this article](https://yoast.com/coordinated-security-release/).

Comment: Hello, I noticed I did a mistake in my code. You can see "plugin_part1-fixed.php" for the code. I just need to set `.esc_url(add_query_arg( "custom_var", $db_table->db_column)).`, you confirm?
Also, now I don't understand the difference beetween the two solutions, I've opened a new question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185268/when-add-query-arg-is-necessary

Comment: Confirmed, that is correct.  I've posted a response to your other question as well.