# When add_query_arg() is necessary?

Tags: query

considering this code, both solutions seems to work fine. What I don't get is, is there any difference between the two solutions?

general_plugin.php

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "custom_var";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

plugin_part1.php

```
...
echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/page/?custom_var='.$db_table->db_column.'">text</a>....'
...
```

plugin_part1-fixed.php

```
...
echo '<a href="https://www.example.com/page/'.add_query_arg( "custom_var", $db_table->db_column).'">text</a>....'
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is, in "plugin_part1-fixed.php" you wouldn't lose existing args.  Consider the url:

```
https://www.example.com/page/?foo=bar
```

Your code in "plugin_part1.php" would output

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/page/?custom_var=column">text</a>
```

Note, the existing arg "foo" has been lost, the code in "plugin_part1-fixed.php" would output:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/page/?foo=bar&custom_var=column">text</a>
```

Note, the existing arg "foo" is still present and your arg has been appended.

Since you don't have any existing args you don't see a difference.  That said, using `add_query_arg()` is still best practice since you don't know if you'll have to interact with another plugin that might also be sending args for whatever reason.

Also, please keep in mind that you should always wrap `add_query_arg()` in `esc_url()` to prevent XSS scripting as better explained [here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185240/add-query-arg-xss-vulnerability#answer-185264)